# python django string rendering issue

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to render a string into a javascript ( which usually works fine for me ) here's my code

HTML:

```
THE USER NAME IS : {{name}} has added app {{has_added_app}}
```

JAVA SCRIPT:

```
<script> 
    <!-- 
       var userName = {{name}}
```

The html version works the javascript fails when I have tried the same rendering in javascript before and it worked.

Comment: Is the javascript file rendered through the django instance or some webserver(lighttpd) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var userName = {{name}}
```

Comes out when you view the HTML source as:

```
var userName = Bob
```

Which is an obvious mistake: missing quotes. But, simply putting quotes around it:

```
var userName = '{{name}}';
```

isn't good enough for the general case. What if the string contains a quote character, or a backslash, or a newline? Best case, your app falls over. Worst case, cross-site-scripting security hole. What's more a `&` or `<` character in the name won't come through properly either, as Django autoescape will probably assume it's in a non-CDATA HTML context and inappropriately &-escape them.

Use the `escapejs` filter instead:

```
var userName = '{{name|escapejs}}';
```

Alternatively use a JSON encoder to turn any basic datatype into JavaScript literal format, not just string. There's [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) in the standard library from 2.6, but note this doesn't escape the `<` character in strings, so for injecting code into a script element you'd have to escape that manually to prevent a `</script>` sequence ending the CDATA element prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

comments for the javascript:

```
var userName = "{{name}}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Django templates are purely textual: they don't "know" that you're creating Javascript.  You need to include the quotes that Javascript needs around a string literal:

```
var userName = "{{name}}";
```

Comment: It's missing the escapejs filter